# How to save UIElements in a Database and restore them later?

Tags: c#, sql, xaml, uielement

Imagine that I created an app which lets you paint paths within a grid.

So when every time you paint something, a new path element is added as children to my Grid UI Element.

So this is my Grid before something has been painted:

```
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="0" PointerMoved="myGrid_PointerMoved" PointerPressed="myGrid_PointerPressed" PointerReleased="myGrid_PointerReleased" ></Grid>
```

And when you paint something the following is added programmtically as a children of the grid above:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathFigure StartPoint="10,50">
        <LineSegment Point="200,70" />
      </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

So each new paint action will add one path like this one as a children of my grid.

Now I would like to save early made Paths in my SQL Database to restore them later but I don't know how I could save an xml XAML UI element in my SQL Database and restore it later.

Is it possible to do this by binding or to save my XAML Objects as a string and parse them later? Whats the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to serialize your XAML-Control and save it as a string to the database.
Later you can load it like this:

```
UIElement cXamlElements = (UIElement)XamlReader.Parse("MY XAML CODE");
```

Like this: [XAML Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82990/XAML-Serialization)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your suggested solution worked for me. I used it in addition with ItemsControl. I'll post my solution when I'm done right here

Comment: Okay I have to correct my answer again, sadly the XamlWriter ist not available in metro style apps. So I need to find another way to serialize my paths ...

Answer (score 0):

As there is no XamlWriter available by today for metro apps, I created my own serialization method for Paths.

If anyone is interested, this is my method:

```
        foreach (Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path path in this._notePaths.Where(myPath => this._newPaths.Contains(myPath)).ToObservableCollection() )
        {
            String myPathObjectString = String.Empty;

            myPathObjectString += @"<Path" + " xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"" + @" Stroke=""" + ((SolidColorBrush)this._notePaths.LastOrDefault().Stroke).Color.ToString()
                + @""" StrokeThickness=""" + path.StrokeThickness + @"""><Path.Data><PathGeometry><PathFigure StartPoint="""
                + ((int)((PathGeometry)path.Data).Figures.FirstOrDefault().StartPoint.X) + "," + ((int)((PathGeometry)path.Data).Figures.FirstOrDefault().StartPoint.Y) + @""">";

            foreach (LineSegment item in ((PathGeometry)path.Data).Figures.FirstOrDefault().Segments)
            {
                myPathObjectString += @"<LineSegment Point=""" + (int)item.Point.X + "," + (int)item.Point.Y + @""" />";
            }
            myPathObjectString += @"</PathFigure></PathGeometry></Path.Data></Path>";
        }
```

The _notePaths is an `ObservableCollection<Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path>`.

The generated string can be later used via the code underneath within a loop to reconstruct you saved paths. Maybe worth to mention that you shouldn't forget the namespace for the XamlReader as this caused lot of problems for me.

```
this._notePaths.Add((Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path)XamlReader.Load(item.PathObject));
```